# Scrolling to a particular position in Safari on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

Is it possible to modify the below code so that it scrolls only to a particular position in Safari and not to the bottom as it does now.

```
javascript:scroll(0,document.getElementsByTagName(%20′body’)%5B0%5D.scrollHeight);
```

I'm okay if you can suggest a completely different code as well for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to a position on the page using scrollTo(h,v)

```
//h = horizontal, v=vertical
window.scrollTo(0,500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLmb9/

Edit: Spaced on the iPhone portion. You have to use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 500);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does this work in Safari on iPhone... Can you please suggest the code I should use as I've tried this before but didn't work for me.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that